# Disable Cloudfront to caching certain path

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have cloudfront in front on API gateway. And I have configure to disable caching on path `/v3/room/{id}/slot` with query `partySize=2&dateTime=2020-10-28T16:00:00.000Z` according to
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/prevent-cloudfront-from-caching-files/ by setting
maximum TTL, minimum TTL, default TTL to 0.

Testing with postman is good does not hit any cache. But when running in production with higher traffic I getting hits on cache show different query result. Any idea why this behavior different when production?

Comment: There is no reason why you should get cached only sometimes. Are you sure you are sending same query all the time?

Comment: What do you see when "getting hits on cache"? Is it in the browser console, the response header, or something else?

Comment: Based on the Cloudfront Report and Analytics and Cloudfront logs,there's around 20% hits. It certainly confirm path `/v3/room/{id}/slot` got cache. But why would seting max TTL, min TTL and default TTL to 0 doesn't take effect?